# Reading text file to matrix in Matlab, with unknown line length

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a text file, that is formatted somewhat like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9
0 11 2 32 45 6 6
1 2
```

I want to read each row and plot a line for each row.The x axes is [1:row.length],the y axes is each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fid = fopen('dat.txt');

line = fgetl(fid);

% if you want everything on the same axis, set it up here
axis([0,20,-10,10])
hold all    

while ischar(line)
  yy = str2num(line);
  xx = 1:length(yy);
  plot(xx,yy)
  line = fgetl(fid);
end
hold off

fclose(fid);
```

Note that feof() is not so good with fgetl(), see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do it is to test for specific characters. Check for the new line character to determine if you're at the end of the current row and the end of file function to see if you're at the end of the file.

Take a look at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feof.html